# how to get the google map's pageX when dragend ,the version is v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this is my code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
   alert(event.pageX)//undefined
});
```

and i want to get the (x,y)  about mouse when dragend..

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can get `event.pixel` and that will give you a x,y object that is relative to the mapDiv's position. If you want absolute position on the page then you will need to add the offset of the mapDiv to that result.